# animation setting in vba of powerpoint

Tags: vba, animation, powerpoint

In vba(PowetPoint), I added animation effects to a shape object.
But any effects I set vanished without a sound effect if I added a sound effect.
The following is sample code.

I splittd their effects to one shape by one effect, the other shape by sound effect.
But I could not solve.

```
Sub hoge()

    Const path As String ="./sound.wav"

    Dim ppSld  As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim shp    As Shape

    Set ppSld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    Set shp = ppSld.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, 10, 10)

    With ppSld.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect( _
          Shape:=shp _
        , effectId:=msoAnimEffectFly)
        effect.Timing.Duration = 10  'duration time
        effect.EffectInformation.SoundEffect.ImportFromFile path  'sound
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: please indent your code by 4 spaces, so that it all shows as code

Comment: your are trying to read the directory that is different from what you think  .... try this line `effect.EffectInformation.SoundEffect.ImportFromFile ThisWorkbook.Path & "\sound.wav"` (windows) or `effect.EffectInformation.SoundEffect.ImportFromFile ThisWorkbook.Path & "/sound.wav"` (mac)

Comment: I omitted the absolute path.Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: i understand that you are using a relative path. .... do you know the value of `./` ?

Comment: my mistake .... you are using powepoint .... that should be `ActivePresentation.Path`